# How to Make an Android ScreenSaver Application?

Tags: android, screensaver, lockscreen

Firstly, I am sorry for the repeat question about ScreeenSaver on Android.
I downloaded on Google Play Store some application about ScreenSaver such as Photo Album Free ScreenSaver, Smoke Free Screensaver, Beach Free Screensaver.
I see that all this application have a same format follow this below image

[image]

Currently, I want to make a application like as that applications I mentioned above.
When android is sleep mode ( Lock Screen), i want to show gallery image and when touch anywhere on screen, it come back to lock screen generally.

I searched but no useful result to me and I really need a reference source code.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it ? Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Daydream? Although note that it only works on 4.2 and up:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Daydream

Comment: I download screensaver app on Play Store and run with version 4.1 not 4.2, it run OK. May be it is not Daydream